# LinearLayout on a ListView

Tags: listview, android-linearlayout

First of all sorry for my bad English.
    I have a very simple application in android. It has 4 buttons that starts a ListView. What      I want to do is that when you press a list item opens a new Layout that has an image downloaded from Internet. 
    The problem I have with the latest, get each item in the list to open the layout.

```
this is my class for control the list

        public class precat extends ListActivity {
    public static ImageView imageView;
    EditText filterEditText;
        //ulo contains my links
    String[] urlo = {"links of my images"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.precat);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        String[] precat = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.precat);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, precat);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        Object o = getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String url = urlo[position];

                //This method show the image. And for now it works XD
        Main.downloadFile(imageView, url);


    }
}

precat.xml is my xml file that contains the ListView an a ImageView to prove that I can see the image.

so... What can i do?
```